# Having 2 callable form validation rules for one field

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I have a personnel table in a database with a unique id (p_id) for each person.
Then there are 2 other tables(authorisations and interventions) with records linked to the personnel table with (p_id)

So i need to delete person from the database, I pass/send p_id to a delete function in the controller to delete the person, but i need to check that no records exists in the authorisations and interventions tables before the person can be deleted.

i use form_validation on p_id

```php
$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('','');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'p_id', 'Autorisations', array(
                'trim', array(
                    'p_id_auth_callable',array($this->Personnel_model, 'check_pers_tasks')
                        )
            ),
            array('p_id_auth_callable' => ' Delete All {field}')
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'p_id', 'Interventions', array(
                'trim', array('p_id_intv_callable',array($this->Personnel_model, 'check_pers_intv'))
            ),
            array('p_id_intv_callable' => ' Delete All {field}')
        );

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $pers_delete_msg['icon']  = 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg';
            $pers_delete_msg['title']  = 'Warning';
            $pers_delete_msg['status'] = 'warning';
            $pers_delete_msg['text'] = validation_errors('<span class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></span>','');// . print_r($post_val,true) ;
        }   
        else{
            //delete person 
        }
```

both these rules work (if i use one of them) i get the correct message.

If i use both rules together like the code above only the message from the last rule is generated.

Can i have 2 callables in one rule combined.

I use a datatable plugin and send the p_id via jquery ajax function to the controller

```
$('#table tbody').on( 'click', '.delete_pers', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var pers_data = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
        $.ajax({
                url: base_url +"personnel/delete_pers/",
                data: { 
                    p_id: pers_data['p_id'] 
                },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                 //display response
                }
                error: function(response){
                 //display
                }
 } );
```

Comment: slightly confusing because you are trying to set rules twice for the same field `p_id` which also has different field names? can you share relevant sections of your form? why don't you just add the two callbacks to the one set rules instead of having 2?

Comment: @Alex, I am trying to figure out how to add 2 callbacks to one rule preferably using the callable method/option so that i can have a custom message. I must say i am a bit new to codeigniter.